# Get emails sent to Org Wide Address

Tags: email, case

We have configured the case auto response rule, if the user replies to the sender - which is an Org wide email, how can i append it to the case?

I already added case thread id to the email but its not appending to the case.

Comment: Have you set up email-to-case in Salesforce?

Comment: Yes - but the sender in case auto response rule cant be the same as email to case

Comment: Have you followed all the steps mentioned in this link? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004218&type=1

Comment: Yes, I already added the case thread id. but when user replies to the org wide address, the case is not appended to the case

Comment: Our case auto response rule sends as the same email as our email to case email.  I'll check to see if we have anything funky under the hood but don't recall having an issue setting this up.

Comment: Hi @gorav when creating an auto response rule, salesforce has this reminder "The sender email address must be either one of your verified organization-wide email addresses or the email address in your Salesforce user profile. It must also be different from your Email-to-Case routing addresses."

Comment: @sforce you are right - we are using our email-to-case address as the reply to address, not as the from address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked salesforce for this. Their response was that whenever we get email replies, it should be sent to the email to case address and not the org wide email address. So we have to set the Reply to Address as the Email to Case Routing address.